# Highcharts crashing Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

Highcharts seems to crash Chrome when I change the 'visible:false' attribute on a spline chart. Chrome seems to be ok if I set all the visible flags to the same thing.

This problem doesn't occur in Firefox

Is this a bug in highcharts?

Demo is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TJ4mc/7/

```
$(function () {
    $('#weeklyRevenue').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{name: 'George Street', data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 5.4]], visible:true}, {name: 'Marrickville', data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 20), 4.5],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 10), 23.7],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 17), 33.6]], visible:false}, {name: 'Liverpool Street', data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 27), 7.3],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 10.7],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 10), 6.8]], visible:false}, {name: 'Moving Average', dashStyle: 'ShortDash', marker:{enabled:false}, data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 5.4]], visible:true}]
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this:

```
[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 5.4]], visible:true}
```

with

```
{x:Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), y: 5.4, visible:true}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work for me because the line is still shown even if visible is false

Demo here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ4mc/13/)

Comment: In case when you would like to hide "point" you can use marker:{
enabled:true
} instead of visible declaration.